# I am trying to set current 'Month, YYYY' as column name in a temp table so as to export it later as a JSON key but am unable to do SO?

Tags: postgresql

I want to set a column name in my temporary table, as current Month, YYYY, but am unable to do so.  I tried searching it online, but found nothing.

I want something like this as a column name: `to_char(now()::DATE,'Mon-YYYY')`

I want the column name, to be the current month-YYYY, so as to calculate date difference in form of months afterwards from it.

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL to do this.  There are other ways of exporting to JSON, though.  Maybe you could tell us what you are trying to do?

Comment: i have to write data to an excel sheet and one of the columns is date difference between the current month, year and the another date's month and year and the column header is the current month, date so i need to set current month, year as a column header can i do it while exporting to json?